# Firebase: Difficulty changing to Nodejs 10 run time

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

The required actions to allow Cloud Functions to continue working for Firebase means moving to nodejs 10.  After making the required changes ,namely changing
1. "engines": {
    "node": "10"},
2. Move to Blaze plan
3. redeploy using the Firebase CLI v8.1.0 or greater.  I am using firebase-tools  8.4.2 (My reading suggests that to update the CLI we update firebase tools.)

Having done this when I do firebase deploy I get 
Error: package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. The only valid choices are: {"node": "8"} and {"node": "6"}.
Of course the program was working prior to the changes above.

The package.json is

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"},
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.4.2",
    "firebase": "^7.7.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.7",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.9.2",
    "pdfkit": "^0.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.9.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

If I simply do npm start it seems to work.

Some clues would be gratefully appreciated

John

Comment: What's your local node version? `node -v`

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade your Firebase CLI to the latest version.  At the time of this writing, it's 8.4.2.  Run `npm install -g firebase-tools`, or whatever you did to install the CLI in the first place.